# downloading from a url with redirects

Tags: r

I am trying to download a files (it could be `png`, `csv` or `pdf`) from an internal url which seems to have redirects. I have tried downloading using `download.file` with `extra=-L` option, the `download` function from `downloader` package and the `httr` package.

However, in all cases I get a file of 768 B. Saving this file as a `.txt` shows that there is a another url within that. I have tried using that url, but without success. I see the following message (along with other information) in the downloaded file

`Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the Resume button once to proceed.`

What works is if I stick that url in the `browseURL` function, I get a prompt to save the desired file.

I need to run the script in batch mode for reproducibility purposes, is there any way to run the `browseURL` in batch mode? or is there any other tool that would be useful here? (I have tried `read.csv`, `fread` etc. without any success). Unfortunately, I can't share the url as it is internal to my organization.

Thanks

Comment: If it's internal, is there any chance you can ask them to share it in a more consistent manner?  Solve the problem at source rather than work around it?

Comment: It looks like the website assumes that the downloading client can run javascript. This is not the case for most R functions. Typically if you need to run javascript, you need to use a package like RSelenium to remote control a web browser to do the evaluation for you. Without anyway to test and debug ourselves, it's not really possible to offer any specific advice since it's not clear exactly what the endpoints are returning. There may be a way to fake an agent string or parse the javascript as a string value to get what you need.